# How to clear cookies in the safariview/native safari (sign out) in the iOS for the google driver SDK

Tags: ios, safari, google-oauth

As you knows, the Google requests the new driver SDK (OAuth2 in the safari view[iOS9,10]/native safari[iOS8] ), 
When the user logouts, the App invokes the following functions(clear keychain, etc. ).

```
//-------------------------------------

[GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization removeAuthorizationFromKeychainForName:g_kGTLRAuthorizerKey];

self.authorization = nil;

//--------------------------------------
```

but when the user login again, he will find that he signed in the safari view/native safari, it is a security issue.

I find a temporary solution for iOS9,10.
we will open the url [https://accounts.google.com/logout] in the safari view when the user signs out, but it is a bad UE. The account can sign out in the safari view truly.

But how to do in the iOS8, if UIApplication opens the url, it jumps to the native safari, it can't return our App.

Need a better solution to sign out in the safari view truly.

Thanks.